# Show that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact $K\subset E$ s.t. $m_\alpha (E\backslash K)<\varepsilon$.

Tags: hausdorff-measure

Let $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ a borelien s.t. $m_\alpha (E)<\infty $ where $m_\alpha $ is that $\alpha -$Hausdorff measure. Show that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact $K\subset E$ s.t. $m_\alpha (E\backslash K)<\varepsilon$.

In fact, I don't know how to prove the claim. I tried to prove it as we prove this result with the Lebesgue measure, but it's not conclusif. There is probably a subtlety I don't see.

Comment: Write the proof you have tried.

Comment: If for $\alpha=0$ we use the counting measure, then the claim is false.

Comment: You may see Falconer, Geometry of Fractal Sets, Theorem 1.6. It could help.

Comment: I'm not sure it is true without some condition on $E$, like being open. If $d=1$ and $E$ is the set of irrational numbers in $(0,1)$, for example.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for your answer. You right, there is one more condition I forgot, $E$ is a borelien.